# How can a thread update a textbox in the page form that is part of the main thread?

Tags: uwp

I'm creating a UWP APP to receive the data from ADC board, I was used WindForm to develop it, it can work, but because UWP doesn't support using Control.Invoke  look through the papers, but I still have no idea how can I start, how can I convert the windform code to UWP code?

The windform code as below

```
 public async Task StartProcess()

        {
            IsCancelled = false;
            Task t = new Task(() =>
            {
                while (IsCancelled == false)
                {
                    I = I + 1;
                    SetTextBox(I);

                }
            });
            t.Start();
        }

     public void SetTextBox(int _Val)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { SetTextBox(_Val); });
            return;
        }
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(_Val);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can a thread update a textbox in the page form that is part of the main thread?

In UWP platform we need to update UI in main thread, You could use [`Dispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.dispatcher?view=winrt-18362#Windows_UI_Xaml_DependencyObject_Dispatcher) to switch to main thread then update ui.

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
  // Update  Textblock
});
```

Comment: @SofyanSH if the answer is helpful please consider accept it.